# How to list the default and available thread schedulers for java programs through command line?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, redhat

What command should be entered to read about default thread scheduler, and to determine if it is a JVM or native thread scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

> What command should be entered to **read about** default thread scheduler, and available alternatives?

The commands you are looking for are `man sched` and `man chrt`.

The first allows you to read about how the scheduler works (at a high level) and the various commands, syscalls and library calls that relate to it.

The second explains the `chrt` which is the main command for adjusting the scheduler properties of a running process.

(If you don't have the `man` command installed ... install it.)

Does this apply to Java?

- There are no standard Java SE APIs for adjusting scheduler policies, beyond the `Thread.setPriority` method<sup>1</sup>.
- Of course, a running JVM *would be* influenced by changes that were made using `chrt`, though it is not clear if this would be "helpful".

---

<sup>1 - Reminder: the influence of `setPriority` on thread scheduling is not specified.  Priorities should be regarded as "best effort", and should not be used as a way to "fix" problems such as race conditions, memory anomalies and so on.</sup>